# unable to send content from client to server using azure functions signalR

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr, signalr-client

we are trying to send content from the client to server using azure functions signalR implementation. however the azure function SendToUser method is not being called.

client code:

```cs
//building connection
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:7071/api").Build();

//starting connection
await hubConnection.StartAsync();

//sending data
hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendToUser", "message", "user");
```

server code:

```cs
[FunctionName("Negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req, [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "ChatHub")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"connection {connectionInfo.Url} {connectionInfo.AccessToken}");
    return connectionInfo;
}

[FunctionName("SendToUser")]
public void SendToUser([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] obj message, HttpRequest req, [SignalR(HubName = "ChatHub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessage, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"message sent by client");
}
```

is this the correct implementation for this ?

Answer (score 0):

- To consume the messages, you will have to use the azure service trigger bindings in the function.
- For that you will need `SignalRTrigger` instead of the `httptrigger` you have passed.

code:

```
[FunctionName("SendToUser")]
public void SendToUser([SignalRTrigger]InvocationContext invocationContext, string message, ILogger logger) 
{
     logger.LogInformation($"{message} "); 
}
```

You can refer these [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) on azure service trigger bindings